# echo specific array elements

Tags: php, return

```
foreach($arrhome as $el){
    echo $el['id'] . '-';
}
```

Result:

`1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-`

Now I want to echo only if `id > 3`

It can be done this way:

```
if($el['id'] > 3){
    echo $el['id'] . '-';
}
```

But I want this way:

```
if($el['id'] < 3){return;}
echo $el['id'] . '-';
```

Nothing is echoed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $row){
    if($row < 3){continue;}
    echo $row . '-';
}
```

I think you confused `return` with `continue`

The above code will do for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arrhome as $el){

    if(!($el['id'] < 3)){

     echo $el['id'] . '-';

    }

}
```

Comment: no, I want to use` return`, or `return false`, or... whatever with `return`

Comment: You should use `continue` return will stop function and try to return something as output

Answer (score 0):

`return` stops your script/function execution. In your case you should use `continue` so as to move to next iteration:

```
foreach($arrhome as $el){
    if($el['id'] < 3) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $el['id'] . '-';
}
```